# Print a grid with certain values

Tags: python

I want to print out this seating chart (using a dash-line grid), with X indicates that the seat is taken.
Each row is numbered from 0 to n-1, and each column is also numbered from 0 to n-1.

The taken seat is a list of tuples to store the location. The first item in each tuple is the row of the seat. The second item is the column.

for example, I have this taken seat:

```
seats = [(0, 4), (6, 2), (3, 7), (5, 5), (3, 5), (7, 7)]
```

with grid:

```
top = 0
bottom = 8
left = 0
right = 8
```

I have tried writing the code as below to print out the grid but don't how to indicate the seat taken?

```
def display(seats, top, bottom, left, right):

board = []
row = bottom - top
column = right - left

for i in range(row):
    board.append([])
    for j in range(column):
        board[i].append("-")

board[0][0] = "-"


for i in range(row):
    print(*board[i])
print(display(seats, 0, 8, 0, 8))
```

and I want the output to be like this format:

```
    ----X---
    --------
    --------
    -----X-X
    --------
    -----X--
    --X-----
    -------X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little explantion create a matrix type of empty seats '-' and then once you have list of seat number to be fullfilled then  loop through the matrix and put those value at seat number to 'X'

```
def display(seats, top, bottom, left, right):
    row = right - left 
    column = bottom-top
    res =[['-' for i in range(row)] for j in range(column)]
    for i in seats:
        res[i[0]][i[1]] = 'X'
    return '\n'.join([''.join(i) for i in res])

seats = [(0, 4), (6, 2), (3, 7), (5, 5), (3, 5), (7, 7)]
print(display(seats,0,8,0,8))
```

output

```
----X---
--------
--------
-----X-X
--------
-----X--
--X-----
-------X
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over all seats and check whether each seat is already taken or not:

```
for i in range(top, bottom):
    for j in range(left, right):
        if (i, j) in seats:
            print("X", end = '')
        else:
            print("-", end = '')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NumPy can make this simpler to implement.

```
import numpy as np

width = 8
height = 8
chart = np.full((height, width), fill_value='-')
```

To index the coordinates, we would need all the coordinates changed from `(x1, y1), (x2, y2), ..., (xn, yn) -> (x1, x2, ..., xn), (y1, y2, ..., yn)`

```
>>> seats = [(0, 4), (6, 2), (3, 7), (5, 5), (3, 5), (7, 7)]
>>> indices = tuple(zip(*seats))
>>> indices
((0, 6, 3, 5, 3, 7), (4, 2, 7, 5, 5, 7))
```

Now we can then index the seat locations to fill in Xs all at once.

```
>>> chart[indices] = 'X'
>>> for row in chart:
...     print(''.join(row))
... 
----X---
--------
--------
-----X-X
--------
-----X--
--X-----
-------X
```